# Html.EditorFor nullable DateTime posting back as null from view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, post, null, editorfor

Lets make the following assumptions; ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor C#, a strongly typed view bound to a view model (not entities etc.), using the Html.EditorFor method,  to edit a nullable DateTime property in the view model.  The two data annotation attributes I added seem to be causing model binding to fail.

Sample view code

```
@model MyApp.ViewModels.NullableDateTimeViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.DateOfBirth)
}
```

Sample ViewModel code

```
[DataType(DataType.Date,
    ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid date in the format dd MMM yyyy")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd MMM yyyy}")]
public class NullableDateTimeViewModel
{
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

Sample controller code

```
[HttpPost]
public ViewResult DoB(NullableDateTimeViewModel nullableDateTimeVM)
{
    ContextDB db = new ContextDB();

    Customer cust = new Customer();

    // DateOfBirth is null so the update fails
    cust.DateOfBirth = nullableDateTimeVM.DateOfBirth.Value;

    db.Customers.Add(cust);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

The data entered in the view is not posting back to the controller when the form in the view is submitted when the data annotation attributes are added.  This means that model binding is failing when using EditorFor with those attributes.  Model binding works fine with TextBoxFor, the value entered in the TextBoxFor input box is passed back to the view with the view model.   What is the problem here with EditorFor and the data annotation validation attributes?

Can we please find a solution that does not involved reinventing the wheel by creating multiple additional classes, helpers, templates and writing a whole lot of additional code?   I am looking for a one or two line solution.

Comment: I don't think you need the `.Value` DateOfBirth should be of type DateTime?. I would set a breakpoint and watch nullableDateTimeVM, you can then check the value of the DateOfBirth property

Comment: I do think the value is needed but I am checking some data annotation attributes to see if they were the problem.

Comment: Yup, the problem is being caused by the two data annotation validation attributes, both cause model binding to fail.  when they are removed, editorfor works fine.

Comment: Do you have a EditorTemplate for DateTime type? If yes can we see the code? When using TextBoxFor you are going to render an input html element. But when you say EditorFor it will look for a EditorTemplate in your project if it is not found it will use the default.

Comment: I am not using an EditorTemplate.

Comment: TextBoxFor works like a charm, regardless of data annotation attributes, EditorFor doesnt work at all with any attribute but Required.

Comment: I am not sure this is an answer but @Html.TextBox("DateOfBirth", Model.DateOfBirth.Value.ToString("dd MMM yyyy"), new { @style="width:6em"}) seems to work pretty well.   The only data annotation I used is Required